# pstore/ramoops won't work on Poco M3, rooted

Tags: root-access, boot, kernel, selinux

I'm trying to use pstore logs on my Poco M3. I tried everything. PSTORE configs are activated on the kernel, pstore module is loaded on the phone, phone is rooted, /sys/fs/pstore is mounted automatically but never contains anything.

```
130|citrus:/ # dmesg | grep pstore
[    0.094327] console [pstore-1] enabled
[    0.094468] pstore: Registered ramoops as persistent store backend
[    1.065975] pstore: Using compression: deflate
[   98.052156] type=1400 audit(1654268897.690:3752): avc: denied { read } for comm="ls" name="/" dev="pstore" ino=1197 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:pstorefs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
[   98.052450] type=1400 audit(1654268897.690:3753): avc: denied { open } for comm="ls" path="/sys/fs/pstore" dev="pstore" ino=1197 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:pstorefs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
```

it looks like selinux is blocking `ls` on `/sys/fs/pstore`. Is there a way to make it always allow `ls` on /sys/fs/pstore, even after reboot?

I already added `androidboot.selinux=permissive` to my boot command line and it's recognized on the phone:

```
130|citrus:/ # getenforce
Permissive
```

Of course, doing

```
citrus:/ # ls /sys/fs/pstore                                                                    
citrus:/ #
```

shows nothing

**UPDATE**: I just learned that permissive means just logging without blocking, so this is not blocking, my pstore is indeed empty. Am I right?

Comment: not sure what you mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHp7g.jpg

Comment: @alecxs my ls-la /sys/fs/pstore is empty. Is your phone a Poco M3? On mine I can't make it work

Comment: could be you're in wrong mount namespace, try su -mm

Comment: @alecxs `citrus:/ $ su -mm
citrus:/ # ls /sys/fs/pstore/                                                                       
citrus:/ # ls -la /sys/fs/pstore/                                                                   
total 0`

Comment: I am using Poco M3 Android 10 with Magisk 24304 Zygisk + LSPosed not sure why it should make any difference?

Comment: Did you make sure that `pstore` is mounted? `mount | grep pstore`.

Comment: @alecxs I think I really tried everything. I'm on Android 11 but I also tried getting pstore from both the official ROM and with my custom kernel with pstore cnfigs activated and so. Won't you upgrade to 11? I think it does not make any difference though

Comment: @IrfanLatif `pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)` I also tried mounting it several times to several differend directories and etc

Comment: @IrfanLatif you may have a look at real issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704286/config-something-on-vendor-phone-defconfig-wont-work-have-to-pass-them-on-mak)

Comment: @alecxs this does not apply to PSTORE, all the PSTORE configs end up in the .config, and the pstore module is mounted on the phone automatically