# unable to boot new kernel with kexec on android

Tags: root-access, boot, kernel, customization

As an alternative to pstore ([pstore/ramoops won't work on Poco M3, rooted](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246939/pstore-ramoops-wont-work-on-poco-m3-rooted)), I'm trying to boot another kernel into my already booted android kernel, to maybe see the kernel logs on boot, using [kexec](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec).

So, the host kernel, I compiled with

```
CONFIG_KEXEC=y
CONFIG_PROC_KCORE=y
CONFIG_KEXEC_CORE=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
```

and it boots.

Then I compiled `kexec` and `strace` to arch64-linux-android and uploaded to the phone together with the kernel `Image`, which is the new kernel, where I only altered the version.

I did

```
./kexec -l ./Image '--initrd=./boot.img-ramdisk' --reuse-cmdline
```

this returns without any errors, after 1 or 2 seconds, then
./kexec -e
which makes the phone screen go black and then the phone reboots after 5 seconds. Should I see a reboot of the phone entirely? What should I see actually?

Here's the output of `./strace ./kexec -e`:

```
execve("./kexec", ["./kexec", "-e"], 0x7fd12b6e58 /* 24 vars */) = 0
getpid()                                = 12649
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7311ee6000
set_tid_address(0x2da560)               = 12649
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", R_OK) = 0
getrandom("\x08\xf8\x28\x00\xe4\xf7\x0a\x36\x2f\xf1\xcf\xa0\x99\xe7\xc5\x47\x29\x46\x85\xcc\x07\xa4\x4b\x81\xe1\x0b\x6f\x9d\x9a\x5a\x0e\x13"..., 40, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 40
mmap(NULL, 1104, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7311ee5000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7311ee5000, 1104, "arc4random data") = 0
sched_getscheduler(0)                   = 0 (SCHED_OTHER)
mmap(NULL, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7311edc000
mprotect(0x7311edc000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
sigaltstack({ss_sp=0x7311edd000, ss_flags=0, ss_size=32768}, NULL) = 0
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7311edd000, 32768, "thread signal stack") = 0
mmap(NULL, 16777216, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310edc000
mprotect(0x731113a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x2d9000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x2d9000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x2d9000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/null", O_RDWR)   = 3
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x20002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x20002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x20002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 24576, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7310ed6000
mprotect(0x7310ed7000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [RTMIN], NULL, 8) = 0
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310ed7000, 16384, "stack_and_tls:main") = 0
munmap(0x7311ee6000, 12288)             = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0711, st_size=5600, ...}, 0) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__/property_info", R_OK) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__/property_info", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=66724, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 66724, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7310ec5000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 11040, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7311ee6000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7311ee6000, 11040, "System property context nodes") = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__/properties_serial", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=131072, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 131072, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7310ea5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:debug_prop:s0", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=131072, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 131072, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7310e85000
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_7, {sa_handler=0x24e380, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTART}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
prctl(PR_SET_TAGGED_ADDR_CTRL, PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE|PR_MTE_TCF_NONE, 0, 0, 0) = 0
mprotect(0x2d9000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x2d9000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310c85000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310c85000, 2097152, "libc_malloc") = 0
munmap(0x7310c85000, 2097152)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 4190208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310a86000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310a86000, 4190208, "libc_malloc") = 0
munmap(0x7310a86000, 1548288)           = 0
munmap(0x7310e00000, 544768)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310a00000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310a00000, 2097152, "libc_malloc") = 0
mmap(NULL, 4194304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310600000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310600000, 4194304, "libc_malloc") = 0
mprotect(0x2ca000, 20480, PROT_READ)    = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7310e84000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7310e84000, 4096, "atexit handlers") = 0
mprotect(0x7310e84000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7310e84000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x7310e84000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/xen", F_OK)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/kernel/kexec_loaded", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
read(3, "1\n", 4096)                    = 2
close(3)                                = 0
madvise(0x7310a0c000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
sync()                                  = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_CLOEXEC, NETLINK_ROUTE) = 4
sendto(4, [{nlmsg_len=20, nlmsg_type=0x12 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|0x300, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=0}, "\x00\x00\x00\x00"], 20, 0, NULL, 0) = 20
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1328, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x49\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x03\x00\x6c\x6f\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00\xe8\x03\x00\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1512, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0a\x00\x03\x00\x62\x6f\x6e\x64\x30\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 2840
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1348, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc3\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x03\x00\x64\x75\x6d\x6d\x79\x30\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1396, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x00\x03\x04\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x03\x00\x69\x70\x5f\x76\x74\x69\x30\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1452, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x01\x03\x05\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0d\x00\x03\x00\x69\x70\x36\x5f\x76\x74\x69\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1452, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x08\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x00\x03\x00\x73\x69\x74\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1504, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x01\x03\x07\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x03\x00\x69\x70\x36\x74\x6e\x6c\x30\x00\x08\x00\x0d\x00"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 7152
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1316, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x09\x00\x00\x00\x41\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x69\x70\x61\x30\x00\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1368, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x41\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x30\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x31\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x32\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x33\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x34\x00"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 8172
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x35\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x36\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x37\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x38\x00"...], [{nlmsg_len=1372, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x39\x00"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 6860
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x03\x00\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61\x31\x30"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 6880
recvfrom(4, [[{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...], [{nlmsg_len=1376, nlmsg_type=0x10 /* NLMSG_??? */, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, "\x00\x00\x07\x02\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x03\x00\x72\x5f\x72\x6d\x6e\x65\x74\x5f\x64\x61\x74\x61"...]], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 6880
recvfrom(4, [{nlmsg_len=20, nlmsg_type=NLMSG_DONE, nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_MULTI, nlmsg_seq=0, nlmsg_pid=12649}, 0], 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 20
madvise(0x7310a0e000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
madvise(0x7310a0c000, 8192, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data8", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data8", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data7", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data7", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data6", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data6", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data5", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data5", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data4", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data4", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data3", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data3", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data2", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data2", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data1", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data1", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data0", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="r_rmnet_data0", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data10", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data10", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data9", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data9", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data8", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data8", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data7", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data7", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data6", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data6", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data5", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data5", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data4", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data4", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data3", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data3", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data2", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data2", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data1", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data1", ifr_flags=0}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_data0", ifr_flags=IFF_RUNNING}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_ipa0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="rmnet_ipa0", ifr_flags=IFF_RUNNING}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip6tnl0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip6tnl0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="sit0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="sit0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip6_vti0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip6_vti0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip_vti0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="ip_vti0", ifr_flags=IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="dummy0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="dummy0", ifr_flags=IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_NOARP}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="bond0", ifr_flags=IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_MASTER|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCSIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="bond0", ifr_flags=IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_MASTER|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_KEXEC
```

In the end it does a `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_KEXEC` and nothing more, then the phone reboots entirely. On the new reboot, the version of the kernel is still the old one, not the new one, so probably it didn't work. Also I tried with a kernel that wasn't booting, and the phone reboots to the old kernel again, confirming the new kernel isn't being booted.

Anyone did this before or know what is happening?